# How to work on Dynamic Localization in Xcode swift Ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, internationalization

If i  change language for entire app , any pods,Tools and frameworks available to translate one language to another Language in swift Ios.

I tried localization for each components in swift but how do i change the entire applications language dynamically using swift Ios.